# Why does moving the imaginary (\$i\$/\$j\$) component in the capacitor element of a transfer function to the numerator flip the coefficient's sign?

Tags: transfer-function

I'm relearning things I lost since college. I remember you have to flip the sign in \$1/(j\omega C)\$ if you want to turn it to \$j/(\omega C)\$, but I do not remember why.

Is there an empirical method for understanding this, so I don't just "do"?

Is there a comprehensive review source for everything DSP, filters, etc that I can consult besides my class notes in the box in the storage? Right now it's Wikipedia...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more of a question for math.stackexchange, but remember that \$j = \sqrt{-1}\$. Therefore, \$\frac{1}{j} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-1}}= \frac{\sqrt{-1}}{-1}=-\sqrt{-1}=-j\$. Note that I multiplied by \$\frac{\sqrt{-1}}{\sqrt{-1}}=1\$ to get rid of the square root in the denominator.

Answer (score 4):

Others have given you the correct answer and you've accepted it, however I'll generalize it for you, as the general situation frequently comes up.

Say you have a complex number expressed as a fraction- it's frequently desirable to separate the real and imaginary portions. To do that you want to get rid of the imaginary part in the denominator. The way we do that is to multiply top and bottom by the **complex conjugate** of the denominator.

If a number is expressed as a+bj (a and b real and j is \$\sqrt{-1}\$) then the complex conjugate is a-bj (it's that easy, just flip the sign on the imaginary part) so the product of the number with its complex conjugate is

\$ (a + bj)\cdot(a - bj) = a^2 + abj - abj + b^2 = a^2 + b^2\$,  which is a real number.

In your example \$ \frac{1}{j}\$,  a=0 and b=1 so the complex conjugate is -j and the denominator 
\$(0 + j)\cdot(0 - j)\$ = +1, so the answer is just -j.

Comment: thanks. Use of the complex conjugate to accomplish this is the key I needed for comprehension. Frustrating to forget your $120k education...

Answer (score 3):

Since, by definition

$$j \cdot j = -1$$

we have

$$-j \cdot j = 1$$

thus

$$-j = \frac{1}{j} $$